# Don't I have to call super() in constructor when class extends Sprite in actionscript3?

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance, sprite, super

I always don't call super() when I extends Sprite.
But doesn't `not calling super()` cause any problem?

Till now, I don't have any problem and I have never seen code which call super() in constructor which class extends Sprite.

How about TextField?
I don't have any problem about TextField, too.

How to know whether I should call super() or not?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If flash doesn't detect a call to `super()` in your child constructor then flash will *implicitly* call `super()` *before* your child's constructor. So:

```
public class Parent {
    public function Parent() {
        trace("Parent");
    }
}

public class Child extends Parent {
    public function Child() {
        trace("Child");
    }
}

new Child();
// Parent
// Child
```

So your child constructor essentially looks like this

```
    public function Child() {
        super(); // <-- Added by flash! 
        trace("Child");
    }
```

So, no, omitting an explicit call to `super()` will not *usually* adversely affect your child's class.

So why would you want to explicitly call `super()`?

The first reason is flash will only ever automatically generate a parameterless call to `super`, meaning that if your parent classes constructor *requires* arguments, then you will need to explicitly call it with those arguments. If you omit the `super(args...)` call in this case, you will get a compiler error.

Second, if even your parent has a parameter-less constructor, you can use `super()` to control the order that the constructors execute. Flash will always insert the call before the childs constructor. So if you wanted to change that order. Then

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    public function Child() {
        trace("Child");
        super()
    }
}
```

would do it in the opposite order. Or you could do:

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    public function Child() {
        // work before initilizing parent 
        super()
        // work after initilizing parent
    }
}
```

Lastly, there is a very obscure way to *not* call your parents constructor by saying:

```
public class Child extends Parent {
    public function Child() {
        if(false) super()
    }
}
```

Because flash sees there is a call, it doesn't insert one. However because its behind a `if (false)` it never gets called, so the parent class never gets initialized.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! How did you know that secret functionality(Automatic Super Insertion)?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f30.html - Under the section called **Constructor Methods**

Comment: Does suppressing the parent constructor mean none of the ancestral constructors get called or just the immediate superclass?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't call `super()` explicitly, Flash will do it automatically **before** all other code in your constructor.

If you call `super()` explicitly, it will be called at the line on which you wrote it.

However, note that you can not set or get any `this` or `super` properties or call any methods before the super class is instantiated

Answer (score 1):

You can safetly exclude the call to the base constructor. If you do not call `super()` in the constructor, the compiler will add a call to the base constructor with no arguments.