# Issue with basic AS3 workers classes

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3

I have followed Lee Brimelow's tutorials ([part 1](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=162), [part 2](http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=163)), but somehow my project doesn't work as expected.

Currently, publishing "src/Secondary.as" to "www/assets/swf/secondary.swf" works properly, however when trying to run "src/Main.as", an error shows up:

```
Exception fault: TypeError: Error #1007: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor.
    at Main/init()[/Volumes/DOCUMENTS/Tests/AS3/test-workers/src/Main.as:52]
    at Main()[/Volumes/DOCUMENTS/Tests/AS3/test-workers/src/Main.as:32]
```

If anybody has time, you can look at [my code on Github](http://github.com/jansensan/test-as3-workers) and maybe see where I screwed up? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I'd try adding a `super()` call in your `Secondary` constructor. I would also recommend checking out the [Flash Builder 4.7 beta](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashbuilder4-7/) that's on Adobe Labs as it has built in support for creating and debugging Workers.

Comment: @NoobsArePeople2 - I think flash automatically adds a super() to any constructor if you don't do it yourself

Comment: @Neil: no, super() is never added unless you explicitly call it. However, that does not mean that there is no constructor, which is what the error tells me.

Comment: @NoobsArePeople2: I tried adding super(), to no avail. That was a nice idea though. Thanks for the suggestion on FB, however I will not purchase a second IDE simply for a new feature.

Comment: @jansensan - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538701/dont-i-have-to-call-super-in-constructor-when-class-extends-sprite-in-actions

Answer (score 2):

As your error message says: the problem raised in Line 52 in your `Main.init()`method. What you try to do there is to create a new instance of `SecondarySWF`. I would say that your embedment of `Secondary` class into `SecondarySWF` doesn't work properly, so it is not available in your init-method. You should set a breakpoint at the first line of your init-method and when the debugger reaches this point check what's in `SecondarySWF`. I expect that there's nothing in that variable, so what your `new SecondarySWF()` then means actually is `new null()`.

Because you embed your secondary.swf with a MIME-type specified the Flex compiler ignores it because it is unable to detect the actual type of data in the loaded file. I found [this post on Adobe's cookbook page](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_to_embed_swf_file_containing_ActionScript_code-12871.html) that explains what you have to do in addition to adding the file using `[Embed]`. Hope this will fit your needs.

Comment: Wow, you're right, it's actually null... Ergh, ok I'll see if that tip you sent works.

Comment: So I managed to get the SWF to not be null (somehow needed to delete and recreate project...) The current issue onto which I now stumble is the fact that workers are not supported? I added traces for some capabilities, and I get that:
  Capabilities.version: MAC 11,4,400,252
  Capabilities.isDebugger: true
  WorkerDomain.isSupported: false
You may check the code at https://github.com/jansensan/test-as3-workers/blob/master/src/Main.as

Comment: Seems to be that you do not have latest version of Flash Player. Should be 11.4.402.265. Could be that your version is a beta or a buggy release that was patched some days later. You should update to the latest one and try again. [Here you get the lastest version for your system](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html)

Comment: Ding ding ding! We have a winner! I updated to the latest version and now it works! I didn't know that since the day of the release new releases had been made. I'll update my code on Github accordingly, thanks!