# AS3: one behaviour to many objects

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm learning AS3 and creating a simple 'Asteroids' game.
I have written a simple class of linear movement:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;

public class lin extends MovieClip {

    private var vx:Number=0;
    private var vy:Number=0;

    public function lin(x:Number,y:Number,sr:Number,spd:Number) 
    {

        this.rotation=sr;
        vy+=Math.sin(degToRad(sr))*spd;
        vx+=Math.cos(degToRad(sr))*spd;

        this.x=x+vx;
        this.y=y+vy;

        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop,false,0,true); 
    }

    public function loop(evt:Event)
    {
        y+=vy;
        x+=vx;

        if (outOfBounds())
            kill();
    }

    public function outOfBounds():Boolean
    {
        return (x>stage.stageWidth || x<0 || y>stage.stageHeight || y<0);
    }

    public function kill():void 
    {
        if(parent)
            parent.removeChild(this);

        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop);
    }

    public function degToRad (deg:Number)
    {
        return deg * Math.PI / 180;
    }

}

}
```

And I need to set this behaviour of movement to several objects (LaserBeam, Asteroids)
I created a new MovieClip with class 'LaserBeam' and wrote this:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import lin;


public class LaserBeam extends MovieClip {

    public var LaserBeamInstance:lin;
    public var LaserSPD=15;     

    public function LaserBeam(x,y,r) {
        LaserBeamInstance=new lin(x,y,r,LaserSPD);

    }
}

}
```

But when I try to run my game, it says:

```
Line 1  1203: No default constructor found in base class lin.
```

What should I do to make many different MovieClips share one behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

UPD: all project files is [here](http://gallerycocoon.ru/Asteroids.zip)

Comment: BTW, you should use capital letters for classes, and lower case letters for instances. It's an ubiquitous standard.

Comment: Also you don't need to import classes that are in the same package. You can remove `import lin`.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling super() from your lin constructor. This is because it inherits from MovieCLip. Properties such as this.rotation won't be initialized until you call the MovieClip constructor with super()

You should also make the class name 'Lin' to follow the standard naming convention.

```
public function Lin(x:Number,y:Number,sr:Number,spd:Number) 
{
  super();
  this.rotation=sr;
  vy+=Math.sin(degToRad(sr))*spd;
  vx+=Math.cos(degToRad(sr))*spd;

  this.x=x+vx;
  this.y=y+vy;

  addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,loop,false,0,true); 
}
```

Comment: No, ActionScript will implicitly call the constructor of the super class if you do not provide a call manually. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538701/dont-i-have-to-call-super-in-constructor-when-class-extends-sprite-in-actions

Comment: Thank you, mfa, for help! But I encountered another problem: movie starts, but when I try to put laser movie clip, it says:     
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at lin/outOfBounds()
 at lin/loop()

Comment: stage is probably not define when you reference it. you need to make sure the clip is added to the display list before that function is called. ADDED_TO_STAGE is an event you can look up for more info.

Comment: I'm not sure, but without laser routine (and when I attach lin class to Laser MovieClip) everything works fine (without asteroids, aof course) - ship flies, laser shoots, etc. Maybe it's not with ADDED_TO_STAGE?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try:

```
 public function lin(x:Number = 1,y:Number = 1,sr:Number = 1,spd:Number = 1)
```

I don't know exactly what's happening, but I think that you have pointed you class "lin" as base class for some of your symbols in your library.
So, that symbols try to construct themselves by calling "lin" constructor, but of cause without any parameters.

---

BTW, Golden rule:

-**variable** names should start from **lowercase** letter

-names of **classes** and **constructors** from **uppercase**

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I'm calling lin from LaserBeam.as like this:

    public function LaserBeam(x,y,r) {
        LaserBeamInstance=new lin(x,y,r,LaserSPD);

    }
e.g. sending correct parameters

Comment: but could you please try setting default parameters x:Number = 1 ... in your constructor method "lin". Just to test my hypothesis.

Comment: I did it, but nothing is changed

Comment: This is strange. I reproduced your error and setting «public function lin(x:Number = 1,y:Number = 1,sr:Number = 1,spd:Number = 1)» helped. Reason was that some Symbols in your library have property "base class" set to "lin". Sorry

Comment: This is strange too, because I haven't any symbols with 'base class' set to 'lin'!

Comment: It seems I got it - I just need to somehow pass an object name to lin. E.g. in LaserBeam.as I need to call lin somehow like this: public function LaserBeam(x,y,r) {
   laserBeamInstance=new lin(x,y,r,laserSPD,LaserObjectName);
  }

Comment: But where to get this object name and how to pass it?

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question:

> What should I do to make many different MovieClips share one behaviour?

You should read about OOP patterns. This book is a great introduction.

[http://www.amazon.com/First-Design-Patterns-Elisabeth-Freeman/dp/0596007124](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124)

In response to your error, I think you are not giving us the whole picture. The error refers to class `lin` being extended, but in the code there are no classes extending `lin`.

Comment: Thank you, @Pier, for taking part in solving my problem. Maybe it is better to look at whole picture? I have packed all my files here: [link](http://gallerycocoon.ru/Asteroids.zip)