# Is it possible to use static variable in subclass from parent class using subclass property, in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance, static-members

In the code below, could you tell me why _myVar is null while g is not, when b.method() is called?

I'm using ActionScript3.

Am I missing something?

```
public Class A{
    protected var _myVar:Type;

    protected method(){
        _myVar // do something with _myVar...

        var g:Type = B.stVar;
    }
}

public Class B extends A{
    public static var stVar:Type;

    public B(){
        _myVar = stVar;
    }
}

public class MainClass{
    mainMethod(){
        B.stVar = new Type();

        var b:B = new B();
        b.method(); // here _myVar is null while g is not!!!! 
    }
}
```

Comment: not really sure, but my guess is because stVar is a static variable. for it to work, _myVar needs to be a static variable as well. You cannot assign a static value to a normal property and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have never assigned a value to a variable `b._myVar`. There is no code in `B()` or `A()` or `B.method` that actually assigns a value to `this._myVar`, and the default value for object type variables is null. `B.stVar` is assigned and available from `b.method` because its assignment happens in `MainClass.mainMethod()`, and since it's static, its value is independent of instances of `B`. A static variable is not attached to any instance of a class, it can be assigned regardless of instances. A dynamic ("normal") variable, like `_myVar`, is attached to a certain instance of a class, in your case either `A` or `B` class instances have this variable and an ability to store a separate value in there.

In your case, you can have a statement `_myVar=new Type()` placed in say `public function A()` that will assign a value to each of the `A` class instances. `B` class instances will *also* get their `_myVar` variables assigned a value, because [Flash implicitly calls `super()` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538701/dont-i-have-to-call-super-in-constructor-when-class-extends-sprite-in-actions) for classes that extend another. So, you add this code to your structure:

```
public class A {
    protected var _myVar:Type;
    public class A() {
        _myVar=new Type();
    }
    ... // rest of code intact
}
```

Then your `_myVar` will get assigned in every instance of `A` and every instance of those classes that extend `A`.

Comment: _myVar is assigned the value of stVar in the class B constructor. So each time a B object is instanciated _myVar gets the value of stVar. When b.method() is called, _myVar is already assigned a value. The reason why I'm doing it this way, is that I need to manipulate stVar in a class A method. I can't put stVar into class A because it's very specific to each subclass of class A.

The reason why it doesn't work may be that a static value can't be assigned to an object variable maybe (as specified in the first comment of my post)?

Comment: Weird indeed. Please put a `trace("Now calling method()")` before `b.method()`, and a `trace(stVar)` into `B()` constructor. Perhaps what you get is a result of `A.method()` being called from elsewhere.

Comment: Found what causes the error (see my answer). Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit awkward to me, but assigning _myVar in the class B constructor like this:

```
_myVar = stVar;
```

doesn't work and assigns null value to _myVar.
I tryed doing it this way:

```
_myVar = B.stVar;
```

and it works perfectly.

Does anyone know why?